# The argument type 'Null Function(DataSnapshot)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<dynamic> Function(DatabaseEvent)'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

void loginAndAuthenticateUser(BuildContext context) async {
showDialog(
context: context,
barrierDismissible: false,
builder: (BuildContext context) {
return ProgressDialog(
message: "Authenticating, Please wait...",
);
});

```
final User? firebaseUser = (await _firebaseAuth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: emailTextEditingController.text,
            password: passwordTextEditingController.text)
        .catchError((errMsg) {
  Navigator.pop(context);

  displayToastMessage("Error: " + errMsg.toString(), context);
}))
    .user;

if (firebaseUser != null) {
  displayToastMessage("You are logged-in now.", context);
  Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()),
      (Route<dynamic> route) => false);

      usersRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) => null);
```

Comment: Getting error in last line?